# Using MySQL to SELECT the MAX of a SUM of the last 5 entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Hey, I'm not the biggest expert with MySQL but here is what I have so far to get the MAX entery

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 
          websites.id, 
          websites.title, 
          websites.url, 
          websites.screenshot, 
          impressions.number, 
          blocks.price 
     FROM websites 
LEFT JOIN blocks ON websites.id = blocks.website 
LEFT JOIN impressions ON blocks.id = impressions.block 
    WHERE status = 1 
      AND blocks.active = '1' 
      AND impressions.number = (SELECT MAX(number) 
                                  FROM impressions)
```

What I want to do is SELECT the max(number) but of the sum of the last 5 entries. I've tried messing around but just can't get it.

Comment: Last five based on what?

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I'm guessing the last five impressions.number

Answer (score 2):

The last five impressions.number this should do it don't know what you want to sum on though

```
SELECT DISTINCT websites.id, 
                websites.title, 
                websites.url, 
                websites.screenshot, 
                impressions.number, 
                blocks.price 
FROM   websites 
       LEFT JOIN blocks 
         ON websites.id = blocks.website 
       LEFT JOIN impressions 
         ON blocks.id = impressions.block 
WHERE  status = 1 
       AND blocks.active = '1' 
ORDER  BY impressions.number 
LIMIT  5
```

If you wanted to sum of blocks.price you could just do

```
 SELECT SUM(lastblocks.price) 
   FROM (
    SELECT 
          price
    FROM   websites 
           LEFT JOIN blocks 
             ON websites.id = blocks.website 
           LEFT JOIN impressions 
             ON blocks.id = impressions.block 
    WHERE  status = 1 
           AND blocks.active = '1' 
    ORDER  BY impressions.number 
    LIMIT  5 ) lastblocks
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last five records, it depends on the column by which you are sorting.  Let's assume this is a date column, so then an example would be:

```
SELECT MAX(n) FROM tbl ORDER BY datecol DESC limit 5;
```